# Passing variables to a child html block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks

At `list.phtml`, I am trying to get product object or product id for child template, which it comes from other module. How I can get product id at that phtml file?
In magento 1.x it was possible via following technique. when used it into magento 2.x is throwing error

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setData()

my custom module layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">PR_Catalog::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="PR\Catalog\Block\Product\Offers" name="category.products.offers" as="offer_list" template="PR_Catalog::product/offers.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>        
    </body>
</page>
```

custom module list.phtml file

```
<?php    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){ ?>

<?php 
        $block->getChildBlock("offer_list")->setData("product", $_product);                            
        echo $block->getChildHtml('offer_list') 
?>

<?php } ?>
```

block class code is

```
<?php
namespace PR\Catalog\Block\Product;

class Offers extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private $product;

    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        var_dump($this->product);die;
      return $this->product;  
    }

}
```

child block phtml file

```
<div class="other-offers">
   <?php echo $block->getProduct()->getId(); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to define public function `setProduct` in your block class:

```
public function setProduct($product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}
```

and then you will be able to get it in your block :)

Also, use `getChildBlock` function instead of `getChild`

Now you have to use your newly created function, `setProduct($_product)` instead of `setData('product', $_product)`.

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Can you post your current code under your question?

Comment: I have posted it.

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: we have to use   `$block->getChildHtml('block_name', false);` i.e. set cache disabled.

Comment: Yes, you are faster than me :) Without second parameter block is cached and product stays the same

Comment: What is the final code?  Could you please share?

Answer (score 5):

Use below code:

```
$block->getChildBlock("offer_list")->setData("product", $_product);
```

to

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('PR\Catalog\Block\Product\Offers')->setProduct($_product);
```

Answer (score 4):

In your block class add the following:

```
protected $product;

public function setProduct($_product){
    $this->product = $_product;
}

public function getProduct(){
    return $this->product;
}
```

In the template file that you call the child block do it like this:

```
<?php /* Start Custom Changes */ ?>
<?php if ($myBlock = $block->getChildBlock('my_child_block')): ?>
    <?php
        $myBlock->setProduct($_product); 
        echo $block->getChildHtml('my_child_block', false);
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php /* End Custom Changes */ ?>
```

Now in your child block template file:

```
<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getId(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to call a phtml file from the block using the below code.

From Static Block:

```
{{block class="Vendor\Extesnion\Block\Customblock" name="customblock" template="Vendor_Extension::filename.phtml" variableName="123"}}
```

From another PHTML file:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Vendor\Extesnion\Block\Customblock")->setTemplate("Vendor_Extension::filename.phtml")->setData("variableName", 123)->toHtml();
```

From XML

```
<block class="Vendor\Extesnion\Block\Customblock" name="block_unique_name" after="-" template="Vendor_Extension::filename.phtml"> 
    <arguments>
       <argument name="variableName" translate="true" xsi:type="string">123</argument>
   </arguments>
</block>
```

In the above code, We have passed the value of **variableName**

Now we need to get that additional data on phtml file like this.

```
$variablevalue = $block->getData('variableName');
```

OR

```
$variablevalue = $block->getVariableName();
```

That's it. Simply clear cache.