# Pass data to getChildHtml() in foreach loop - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I'm trying to pass data to a block within a foreach loop.

I've created a new block search.phtml and added it to my layout.xml as follows:

```
       <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="Amrita_CatalogSearch::advanced/form.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_search" template="Amrita_CatalogSearch::advanced/search.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="my_arg" xsi:type="string">testvalue</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
</block>
```

I want to set the value of my_arg dynamically within a loop and render the search block, where i will retrieve the value of my_arg.

i've tried the following within the parent block:

```
$block->GetChild('search')->SetData('my_arg', $_code);
                            $block->getChildHtml('search');
```

and then to retrieve:

```
$_code = $block->getData('my_arg')
```

This throws an error:

```
Invalid method Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form::GetChild(Array
(
    [0] => search
)
)
```

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: In GetChild and SetData  first letter must be in lowercase

Comment: $block->getChild('search')->setData('my_arg', $_code);
                    $block->getChildHtml('search'); isn't working either, getting the error Call to a member function setData() on null

Comment: You dont have block with name "search". Try this `$block->getChild('catalogsearch_advanced_search')`

Comment: I tried that too, same error.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/112466/2721) will be usefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this as follows,

```
$block->getChildBlock("select")->setProductAttributes($_attribute, $_code);
                    echo $block->getChildHtml('select');


$_attributes = $block->getProductAttributes();
```

where getProductAttributes/setProductAttributes are declared in a custom class

```
    namespace Amrita\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced;

class Form extends Advanced\Form{

    private $attribute;
    private $code;

    public function setProductAttributes($attribute, $code, $attributeTitle, $maxQueryLength, $isActive)
    {
        $this->attribute = $attribute;
        $this->code = $code;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getProductAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'attribute' => $this->attribute,
            'code' => $this->code
    }
}
```

and in the layout.xml,

```
     <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch_advanced_form">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Amrita_CatalogSearch::advanced/form.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
                    <block class="Amrita\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_search" as="search" template="Amrita_CatalogSearch::advanced/search.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it's now rendering the block:

```
$block->getChildHtml('catalogsearch_advanced_search')->setData('my_arg', $_attribute);
```

I still have an error

```
Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on null
```

within the search block

```
$_attribute = $block->getData('my_arg');
$_code = $_attribute->getAttributeCode()
```

i want to pass a single attribute object (rather than an attribute collection) but i can't get it to work. Is this the correct syntax?

```
 <arguments>
                        <argument name="attribute" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="my_arg" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

getChild etc are not supported in Magento 2.

Whilst I haven't got that much experience with it yet, I have done something similar for a test module. It doesn't answer your question exactly but it may help you on the way:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form')->setMyArg($_attribute)->toHtml();
```